# Suppress Vary:* response headers generated by Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

Our Spring Boot app generates `Vary` response headers for the transfer of static resources (also for REST API calls by the way). I would like to suppress this, but I find no configuration option to do this.

The following headers are generated:

```
Vary:Origin
Vary:Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary:Access-Control-Request-Headers
```

Setting and playing with various cache properties `spring.resources.cache.*` was not successful. The `spring.resources.cache` property is described in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html.

Is there a valid options to supress the generation of theses headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's check this hack to supress every header in `HttpServletResponse`.

By default it is not possible to remove header from `HttpServletResponse`, the interface doesn't support remove header or something else.

Using a custom `HttpFilter` it is possible to supress adding headers by doing a litle hack.

In the filter chain you can add an `HttpServletResponseWrapper` and overrite the `addHeader` and `setHeader` methods. Now it's the custom logic which haeder are set in `HttpServletResponse`. Make sure that your filter is one of the first filter wthin the chain.

Check this example `@Component` if you are using Spring Boot (this trick is also possible with Java EE, therefor please use Java EE filter spec to enable the filters):

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
public class VaryHeaderFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, new HttpServletResponseWrapper((HttpServletResponse) response) {
            @Override
            public void addHeader(String name, String value) {
                if (!HttpHeaders.VARY.equals(name)) {
                    super.addHeader(name, value);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void setHeader(String name, String value) {
                if (!HttpHeaders.VARY.equals(name)) {
                    super.setHeader(name, value);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Vary` headers are set as soon as `CORS` is activated.

`CORS` may have been activated by the `@CrossOrigin` annotation in `*Controller` classes.

However, `CORS` may also be set via `SecurityConfig`

```
@Override
protected void configure (HttpSecurity http) throws an exception {
    ...
    http.cors ();
    ...
}}
```

See also this issue for detailed information:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18378

See also `CORS` specification beacuse of `Vary` header:

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

> If the server specifies a single origin rather than the "*" wildcard,
>   then the server should also include Origin in the Vary response header
>   — to indicate to clients that server responses will differ based on
>   the value of the Origin request header.

Answer (score 1):

The spring guy added this behavior in 5.2: 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/d27b5d0ab6e8b91a77e272ad57ae83c7d81d810b#diff-d854062b0e7c407eadbc755d6226f401R62

changelog: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#cors-handling